# Zero conditional mean and zero correlation

Tags: probability, statistics, linear-regression

$\newcommand{\Cov}{\mathrm{Cov}}$
$\newcommand{\E}{\mathrm{E}}$
Is $E(Y|X)=0$ equivalent to $\Cov(X,Y)=0$?

I know $E(Y|X)=0$ implies $\Cov(X,Y)=0$, because

$\Cov(X,Y) = \E(XY) - \E(X)\E(Y) = \E[\E(XY|X)]-E[X]E[E(Y|X)]=0$

But is the other way around true? Does $\Cov(X,Y)=0$ imply $E(Y|X)=0$?

Can anyone give a proof or disproof? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Let $Y=c$ a.s. with $c\neq0$.

Then $\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)=0$ but $\mathsf E(Y\mid X)=c\neq0$.

Comment: Does the answer change if we further assume $E[Y]=0$?

Comment: @Anvit I don't think that conditions on *expectations* like $E[Y]=0=E[XY]$ are enough to imply that *random variable* $E(Y|X)$ is degenerated and takes value $0$ a.s.